# return the "top" property of a tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs for which I have two buttons. Clicking on the buttons, I want to alert the "top" style property of the divs, in the codes as below:

However, when I click on the buttons, what they return is "undefined". I'd be grateful if you kindy let me know where I am going wrong.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="section_1"></div>
    <div id="section_2"></div>
    <button id="edit_1" onClick="edit(1);"></button>
    <button id="edit_2" onClick="edit(2);"></button>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function edit(clicked_edit) {
    var tp=document.getElementById('section_'+clicked_edit).top;
    alert(tp);
}
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

body{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#F4F4F2;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family:verdana;
}

#container{
    width:820px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    border: dashed 2px blue;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#section_1{
    width:800px;
    height:198px;
    border-top: solid 2px #D24726;
    background-color:#ffcccc;
    top:0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
}

#section_2{
    width:800px;
    height:198px;
    border-top: solid 2px #14826D;
    background-color:#C1FBDE;
    top:200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
}

#edit_1{
    width:50px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:740px;
    margin-top:15px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:4;
    background-color:red;
}

#edit_2{
    width:50px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:740px;
    margin-top:215px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:4;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: i think your are trying to get the position try `offsetTop` instead of `top` http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/mev4jbor/1/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes I forgot about `offsetTop`. You could post it as answer, because it's correct. Even though it's not the same as `top` style property. However in this case maybe this is what OP actually needs.

Comment: @ Vitorino Fernandes  Indeed correct and helpful thanks

Answer (score 4):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/mev4jbor/1/)

change `.top` to `.offsetTop` you will get the position

```
function edit(clicked_edit) {
    var tp = document.getElementById('section_' + clicked_edit).offsetTop;
    alert(tp);
}
```

**Edit**

made changes to set the div to same position as the offset value

```
function edit(clicked_edit) {
    var tp = document.getElementById('section_' + clicked_edit).offsetTop;
     document.getElementById('expansion').style.top = tp + 'px'; // need to add this
     document.getElementById('expansion').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: @ Vitorino Fernandes - I have an expansion div that should open under the clicked edit. But, I could not assign the offsetTop to change the position of the "expansion" div. Would you take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/hnml/yv2agupk/1/

Answer (score 1):

For that you would use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) method of the `window` object in this way:

```
function edit(clicked_edit) {
    var el = document.getElementById('section_'+clicked_edit);
        top = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('top')
    alert(top);
}
```

```js
function edit(clicked_edit) {
    var el = document.getElementById('section_' + clicked_edit),
        top = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('top')
    alert(top);
}
```

```css
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
body {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#F4F4F2;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family:verdana;
}
#container {
    width:820px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    border: dashed 2px blue;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
#section_1 {
    width:800px;
    height:198px;
    border-top: solid 2px #D24726;
    background-color:#ffcccc;
    top:0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
#section_2 {
    width:800px;
    height:198px;
    border-top: solid 2px #14826D;
    background-color:#C1FBDE;
    top:200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
#edit_1 {
    width:50px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:740px;
    margin-top:15px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:4;
    background-color:red;
}
#edit_2 {
    width:50px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:740px;
    margin-top:215px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:4;
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="section_1"></div>
    <div id="section_2"></div>
    <button id="edit_1" onClick="edit(1);"></button>
    <button id="edit_2" onClick="edit(2);"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Side-note: `getComputedStyle` is only partially supported in IE 9, and fully supported starting at IE 11. (No problem in other browsers, obviously)

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, thank you. That's also why I think Vitorino Fernandes answer is better here.